# GNU Make Pattern Rules on Windows

Tags: c, windows, makefile, gnu

I've been  having some trouble lately while using a makefile that I've been using on Linux without trouble for quite a while now.
It's logic consists in generating strings with all the objects, source files and headers used for the compilation process; but I've only written specific rules to objetcs that need some kind of special treatment, and for the rest I've used the following pattern rule:

```
obj/%.o:    src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

On Linux it's working, but when I try to use on Windows, with some changes of course, it doesn't and i get the following error:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'obj\battle.o', needed by 'programa'. Stop

I've been trying to figure it out alone but it has been hard.

Linux' makefile:

```
SOURCES := $(shell ls src/*.c)
SUBST1  := $(subst src/,obj/,$(SOURCES))
OBJECTS := $(subst .c,.o,$(SUBST1))
HEADERS := $(shell ls headers/*.h)
CC = gcc
LFLAGS   = -g -I headers/ -o programa -Wall -pedantic
CFLAGS   = -g -I headers/ -c -Wall -pedantic

programa:    $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -lm

obj/arvore.o:   src/arvore.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lm $< -o $@

obj/main.o: $(HEADERS)

obj/%.o:    src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:

ifneq ($(shell ls obj/*.o),)
    rm obj/*.o
endif

ifneq ($(findstring ./programa, $(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -perm -111 -type f)),)
    rm programa
endif

##############################################################
.PHONY = programa organize clean
```

Windows' makefile:

```
AA = aa
SOURCES := $(shell dir /b /s src\*.c)
SUBST1  := $(subst $(shell cd)\, ,$(SOURCES))
SUBST2  := $(subst src\,obj\,$(SUBST1))
OBJECTS := $(subst .c,.o,$(SUBST2))
HEADERS := $(shell dir /b /s headers\*.h)
CC = gcc
LFLAGS   = -g -o jogo -Wall -pedantic
CFLAGS   = -g -c -Wall -pedantic

programa: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -lm

obj\main.o: src\main.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

obj\arvore.o: src\arvore.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lm $< -o $@

obj\%.o: src\%.c;
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
ifneq ($(findstring .o, $(shell dir /b obj\*.o)),)
    del obj\*.o
endif

ifneq ($(findstring jogo.exe, $(shell dir /b *.exe)),)
    del jogo.exe
endif
```

PS: The variable AA on windows' makefile, it's a temporary fix, since without it normally it "eats" a char from the first variable, e.g let's say CC = gcc it's the first one, the command on cmd goes "cc -g [...]" if you know why that happens I'd like to know too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt it's the cause here, but the `subst` that removes the directory prefix in SUBST1 could use `,,` as the replacement, rather than `, ,`...it's possible there's whitespace left in a bad place.

Answer (score 3):

- You have a spurious `;` after the pattern rule
- make on windows won't work properly if you use backslashes internally, it's far easier to use forward slashes and replace then only when needed for windows tools that don't work without them, such as `del`.
- You don't need to use windows shell for a lot of the file processing, make has internal features for this.
- Compiling flags have no effect when linking (`-Wall` etc.), and linking flags have no effect when compiling (`-lm`)
- You've forced the final executable to depend on all of the headers, when object files should depend on exactly the headers they need. Use gcc's dependency generation feature `-MMD` etc, and make's `-include` feature instead.
- `CC` expands to `cc` by default, which should be a link or a copy of your default compiler, in your case just copy `gcc` to `cc` in the bin directory
- make has built-in rules and recipes for a lot of common operations, recycle them

Your makefile can be condensed as follows:

```
sources := $(wildcard src/*.c)
objects := $(sources:src/%.c=obj/%.o)
deps    := $(objects:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP
CFLAGS   := -g -Wall -pedantic
LDLIBS   := -lm

jogo.exe: $(objects)
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

clean:
    -del $(subst /,\,$(objects) $(deps)) jogo.exe

-include $(deps)
```